# Would it be better to use char(8) or int column type to represent all integers from 10000000 to 99999999

Tags: sql

I need to create reference numbers that are easily communicated verbally.  They should not be assigned sequentially nor duplicated. (by this I mean they will be assigned randomly within the range)  I will not be using them for computations.  They are strictly for usage as identifiers.

I am thinking a lookup table with all possible 8 digit integers will be the most straightforward way to accomplish this.  E.g. from 10000000 to 99999999. This would allow assigning randomly from the remaining pool instead of randomly generating in batches to get around collisions.

Would it be more efficient to store them as a char(8) or 32bit int primary key?

Would the answer be different if I used 9 digit or 10 digit values instead?

I have considered using alphanumeric identifiers as well, but I think it would be less error prone to rely on numeric digits as verbal communication is a priority.

-- edited to clarify the assignment needs to appear random --

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if it you plan on doing math with it, numeric.  If not, Character. The only exception I would ever have to that rule of thumb is Auto increment sequences.

Comment: @xQbert That is what I usually stick to but I've never dealt with this particular case before.  It seemed like something that might be an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It's not clear that eight-digit numbers are especially significant here.)

A potentially big problem with using a randomized table is that it can quickly become a hot spot. Applications must a) select the next usable value from that table, b) update a column in that table (to make sure that value doesn't get selected again), c) insert that value into your main table.

If I were using a dbms that supported sequences, I might try something like this.

- Use whatever integer data type gives you the required range.
- Use a sequence generator with the right range to generate sequential integers in the target range.
- Use the [multiplicative inverse](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/) to obfuscate the integers.

Here's an example using PostgreSQL. (Not rigorously tested.)

```
create sequence wibble_seq
  increment by 1
  minvalue 10000000
  maxvalue 99999999
  start with 10000000
  owned by none
;
```

You *could* just as easily start with 1. These numbers aren't as important as their multiplicative inverses. Unless, that is, you're doing something like obfuscating invoice numbers, in which case you want the sequence to generate internal invoice numbers, and the multiplicative inverse to generate external invoice numbers.

```
create table wibble (
  reference_num integer primary key
    default (nextval('wibble_seq') * 387420489 % 1000000000),
  added_time timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

After inserting three rows, this is what I get.

```
select *, reference_num::bigint * 513180409 % 1000000000 as original_num
from wibble;
```

```
reference_num  added_time                    original_num
--
890000000      2014-05-19 22:25:43.912445    10000000
277420489      2014-05-19 22:26:18.791284    10000001
664840978      2014-05-19 22:26:23.342876    10000002
```

Answer (score 1):

int, faster look up, less bytes 
10 digits int32 doesn't cut it then due to 4.32 being around the max so forced to use char(8) though I'd probably just use a bigint datatype

Edit: 10 digit char(8) wouldn't work either unless you're doing scientific notation

you would need to update both data types to a bigger format.

Comment: 10 digit 32bit int was an oversight.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: well I meant char(9) or char(10) vs int32, not a 10 digit char 8.  But thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have identifiers, I would recommend storing them as characters.  They are not being used for arithmetic, so there is no advantage -- other than storage space -- to using numeric types.

Another advantage is that you can extend your range to include values that start with 0.

I don't see why you need to create a table with all the values.  If you don't want an auto-incremented value, then you can generate random numbers and use a unique index.  This might require multiple tries, but so long as you don't have too many values (say 50% of the possible ones or less), then just a handful of tries should be sufficient to get a new value.

Comment: I think it would become increasingly difficult to randomly find available numbers... although I guess I could delay using the lookup table until it became necessary.  Here is an example list of probability of random collision at different group sizes.  Using the entire range of unsigned 32bit integers, there is a 50% chance of collision after only 77,000 entries

Comment: @user319862 . . . That is why you would use a unique index and generate multiple random numbers.  Of course, you could have a lookup table.  I'm just thinking that the overhead of checking a few values is less than the effort to get another unused value, but it does depend on the application.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where practicality trumps the simple rules-of-the-thumb we all learn early in our careers. Sure, you can use characters because you don't do arithmetic on the codes, you just have to write code that transactionally generates unique consecutive codes for you and make sure it's safe and fast. Or you can simply use a number `IDENTITY` field with an appropriate seed, and let the database do the hard work for you. That's exactly what `IDENTITY` is for.